# Regex to allow special only between alpha numeric

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a REGEX which should validate only if a string starts and ends with Alphabets or numbers and should allow below special characters in between them as below:

```
/*
hello  -> pass
what -> pass
how @@are you -> pass
how are you? -> pass
hi5kjjv  -> pass
8ask -> pass
yyyy. -> fail
! dff -> fail
NoSpeci@@@alcharacters -> pass
Q54445566.00 -> pass
q!Q1 -> pass
!Q1 -> fail
q!! -> fail
#NO -> fail
0.2Version -> pass
-0.2Version -> fail
*/
```

the rex works fine for above query but the issue is it expects at least two valid characters:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+$%_=;?\'\,\!-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

failing in case if we pass:

```
a -> failed but valid
1 -> failed but valid
```

I tried replacing + with * but this was accepting special characters from the start (@john) which is wrong.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+  with [A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Comment: `how are you?` is shown as `pass` but it is not ending with alphanumeric?

Comment: Try it like this `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+$%_=;?',!-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$` https://regex101.com/r/nqIX8P/1 but yes, the `?` at the end should not match as it is no alphabet or number.

Comment: @Thefourthbird works fine, let me test for edge case

Comment: @anubhava if the string is only one character(alphabet or Number) it is failing.

Comment: @YaseerHussain: You can just use `^[A-Za-z0-9](?:.*[A-Za-z0-9?])?$`

Comment: @anubhava this works fine for all special characters, but I need specific characters ```! #$%;&'+,./=?@_-```

Comment: ok then use: `^[A-Za-z0-9](?>[! #$%;&'+,./=?@\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9?])?$`

Comment: both of your regex are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[! #$%;&'+,./=?@\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9?])?$
```

Or if your regex flavor supports atomic groups then use a bit more efficient:

```bash
^[A-Za-z0-9](?>[! #$%;&'+,./=?@\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9?])?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ba8cav/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[A-Za-z0-9]`: Match an alphanumeric character
- `(?>[! #$%;&'+,./=?@\w-]*[A-Za-z0-9?])?`: *Optional* atomic group to match 0 or more of a specified char in `[...]` followed by an alphanumeric or `?` characters
- `$`: End

Comment: if you are using property file to read the regex use this:  ```^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+$%_=;?\'\,\!-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$```

Comment: Good one and we can avoid some escaping: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+$%_=;?',!-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$`

Comment: I have spring boot application for backend, from properties I read this regex into API, this works only with escaping characters, but your answer should work in general, unlike my special case. great work-thanks.